# What is the simplest way to make a grouped bar graph where you can input your own values in Stata?

Tags: graph, bar-chart, stata, grouped-bar-chart

I've got say two groups a and b and a has values (4, 8, 2, 4, 2) and b has values (1, 5, 2, 8, 7) for time points 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. How do I make a bar graph out of these values without having to clear my data set and make new variables?

Time will be the x axis and value will be the y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need new variables but they don't have to be aligned with existing data. Several ways to do it. You could type in new variables in the Data Editor or use `input`, or here is self-contained code with some of the many ways to do it.

```
clear 

mat a = (4, 8, 2, 4, 2) 
mat b = (1, 5, 2, 8, 7) 
mat t = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 

set obs 10 
gen y = a[1, _n] 
replace y = b[1, _n-5] in 6/10 
gen t = t[1, _n]
replace t = t[1, _n-5] in 6/10 
gen which = cond(_n <= 5, "a", "b")

set scheme s1color 
graph bar (asis) y, over(t) over(which)

gen a = a[1, _n] 
gen b = b[1, _n]

graph bar (asis) a b in 1/5, over(t) 

gen t1 = t-0.2
gen t2 = t+0.2

twoway bar a t1, barw(0.4) || bar b t2, barw(0.4) xla(1/5) legend(pos(12) row(1)) xtitle(t)
```

You should omit the command

```
set obs 10
```

if you already have 10 or more observations in the dataset.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what you are doing here though?

Comment: See my paper on matrices as look-up tables. Otherwise I am just using standard commands. If you are puzzled by a specific command, let me know which one.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand most of it. I get that you are trying to make a variable with the numbers and then filling the rest of the cells in with dots but the rest I don't understand what you are doing. Like the in 6/10 one? And the time? My knowledge of Stata is very basic. I only started learning it here and there a couple of months ago.

Comment: The in qualifier is basic: there is help on it. Also you said yourself that the x axis was time.